# Open Convex Subsets of Dense Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, self-learning, topological-vector-spaces

So I asked this question yesterday, [Existence of Non-Trivial, Convex, Open Set in $C_{\mathbb{C}}[0,1]$ Under $L^{0}$ Metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755331/existence-of-non-trivial-convex-open-set-in-c-mathbbc0-1-under-l0), and it made my start wondering the following...

Suppose the following:

- $Y$ is a topological vector space
- X is a linear subspace  of Y endowed with the subspace topology
- X is dense in Y
- U is open and convex in X.
- V is an open set in Y s.t. $U=V\cap X$
- $Conv(V)$ is the convex hull of V

Question: Is it necessary that $U=Conv(V)\cap X=V\cap X$?

Comment: I've been playing with this problem. I am able to construct counterexamples where V need NOT be convex if X is not dense.

Comment: Do you mean $U = V \cap X$ in your last bullet? Note that $V$ is not uniquely determined. In case $U = X$, you can take $V = Y \setminus \{y_0\}$, where $y_0 \not\in X$.

Comment: @gerw, ugh, yeah, I noticed that just before I saw your comment. Thanks for the input!